# Unable to use a variable in a jQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, lightbox

I have been trying to solve this problem for a long time now. I have no idea what I have been doing wrong.

I know you can use a variable in the jQuery selector and it works, like this:

```
var dude = "_world";
 $("#hello" + dude).hide();
```

So I wanted to use it in this code for a jQuery lighbox:

```
$(document).ready(
function()
{
    $('.gallery_image_preview').click(
    function(e)
    {
        id = e.target.id;
        $('#lightbox_background').fadeIn();

        $(".lightbox_content#image_" + id).fadeIn();

    });

    $('.lightbox_content').find('.lightbox_close').click(
    function()
    {
        $('#lightbox_background, .lightbox_content').fadeOut();
    });

});
```

Which basically animates a div with an image. However, I can not get this to work. When I replace the 'id' variable with a number, it works like it's supposed to, but the variable somehow does not seem to return any value.

Any help would be appreciated. I spent hours on this one :)

Please, bare in mind, that I am a beginner on a journey to become a great programmer.

Comment: What does your HTML look like? And you realise you have an extra leading-quote `"` in your posted jQuery before the `$`?

Comment: `id` attributes which begin with a number are invalid and will cause errors. Try changing the id to begin with a `A-Z` character

Comment: there is no need to filter for id selectors, it will not improve the performance

Comment: It would help a lot if you would also post a sample of the relevant HTML, because it's not clear what it is you're trying to control.

Comment: Is `console.log(e.target);` what you expect? Debugging 101.

Comment: Rory McCrossan, thank you very much. This solved it. The id values have to have a letter in them, only number won't do. Since I was stupid enough not to include the html, you couldn't have known that. I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all you dont need to filter your id selectors by prepending the class name before it, it doesnt improve the performance. also you are doing it incorrectly and probably that is the reason it is failing.

either do:

```
$("#image_" + id).fadeIn();  // the correct way

or

$(".lightbox_content #image_" + id).fadeIn();  //which will work but is useless prepending the class selector
```

see: http://jsfiddle.net/KpUZX/

Also from your comments the problem might be with the retrieving the id.. why dont you try:

```
id = $(this).attr("id");
```

Answer (score 2):

The selector `".lightbox_content#image_" + id` is never going to make sense.  If you have images with "id" values, you just need `"#image_" + id`.  What you've got now will only work if the "lightbox_content" element itself has the id you're looking for.  You could put a space before the "#" but it's (probably) pointless. (Seeing your actual HTML would help confirm that.)

However, since you've already got a reference to the target DOM element (both in `this` and `e.target`), you can just use that directly:

```
    $(this).fadeIn();
```

Comment: Nevertheless `"#image_" + id + ".lightbox_content"` may work.

Comment: Thank you, I have tried using $("#image_" + id), but it did not work. However, if I use $("#image_"+5) it suddenly works. "this" would not work, because I need the "image_" word to be there.

Comment: Well what exactly are your "id" values? If you don't post the HTML, we can't help. @kirilloid yes it might but we don't know much about the markup.